# Adding WMS (Web Map Service) maps on google maps

Tags: jquery, .net, google-maps, wms

I have a map server which url is :

x.x.x.x/services/MapServer?f=abc

When I write this url in a server I can see wms map ,which shows city boundaries,ways between cities etc. Now I'm working on google maps, and I will add(overlaying) the Wms map on Google map, İs there any way to adding Wms on Google map,I'm using Google Map API V3.I will make this processs wtih jquery